# Неправильно работает рандомизация

Tags: c#

Есть код, который рандомизирует общий список, и даёт на выход N-элементов Иногда он возвращает всё время одинаковые данные, иногда норм работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public static IList<TSource> RandomizeCollection<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source, int maxItems)
        {
            int randomCount = source.Count > maxItems ? maxItems : source.Count;
            int?[] randomizedIndices = new int?[randomCount];
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < randomizedIndices.Length; i++)
            {
                int randomResult = -1;
                while (randomizedIndices.Contains((randomResult = random.Next(0, source.Count))))
                {
                    //0 -> since all list starts from index 0; source.Count -> maximum number of items that can be randomize
                    //continue looping while the generated random number is already in the list of randomizedIndices
                }

                randomizedIndices[i] = randomResult;
            }

            IList<TSource> result = new List<TSource>();
            foreach (int index in randomizedIndices)
                result.Add(source.ElementAt(index));

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Сделал threadsafe рандом - заработало. Можно удалить можно оставить, на ваше усмотрение

Answer (score 1):

Возможно слишком быстро идут два вызова подряд этой функции - и `Random` оказывается инициализирован одинаковым семенем. Вынесите метод в отдельный класс, и создавайте Random один раз вне функции. должно заработать